# How to modify value being asserted inside of the config

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am wondering if there is a way to modify asserting value in the config.

For example,
I have the following assertion

```
customer.Should().Be(c, config => config.Excluding(c => c.Updated));
customer.Updated.Should().Be(c.Updated.ToString());
```

Is there any way to have conversion to string as part of the assertion instead of a separate assertion.

Something like this

```
customer.Should().Be(c, config => config.SomeFunction(c => c.Updated.ToString()))
```

Comment: What happens if you try using `BeEquivalentTo`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here

[Object graph comparison: Auto-Conversion](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#auto-conversion)

You should be able to instruct the assertion to

> attempt to convert the value of a property of the subject-under-test to the type of the corresponding property on the expectation

```
customer.Should().BeEquivalentTo(c, options => options
    .WithAutoConversionFor(x => x.Path.Contains("Updated")));
```

or

```
customer.Should().BeEquivalentTo(c, options => options.WithAutoConversion());
```